# ¿Cómo modificar el mensaje de un commit en particular?

Tags: git, git-commit

Quisiera modificar el mensaje de un commit en particular, se que con el siguiente comando puedo modificar el mensaje del ultimo commit realizado:

```
git commit --amend -m "your new message"
```

¿Pero cómo puedo modificar el mensaje del antepenultimo commit realizado? ¿Es posible?

Comment: El antepenúltimo commit es HEAD~3 el comando git rebase es `git rebase -i HEAD~4` nuevamente, recuerda no reescribir la historia de commits que ya existan en un remote

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Puedes usar `git rebase` para ir a un commit viejo. Por ejemplo, si tienes estos commits:

```
HEAD
Commit1  aac723ab
Commit2  cdc213ff
Commit3  aff521cd
```

y quieres modificar el `Commit 2` harías lo siguiente:

```
git rebase --interactive cdc213ff^
```

En el editor que saldrá (el default) pon `edit`, `r` o `reword` en lugar de `pick` en la línea del commit que desees modificar.

Algo así:

> Antes:

```
pick cdc213ff Mensaje del commit que deseas modificar
```

> Después:

```
reword cdc213ff Mensaje del commit que deseas modificar
```

Has tus cambios (si tuvieras) y luego haces el nuevo commit:

```
git commit --all --amend -m "Tu nuevo mensaje"
```

Y luego de eso:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Para regresar a tu `HEAD` anterior.

**Precaución:**

Esto no es recomendable en repositorios públicos dado que si hay programadores que basaron sus cambios en los commits posteriores, tendrán una especie de código fantasma y causará muchas confusiones. Pero en tu caso, si sólo vas a cambiar el mensaje entonces no hay mucho problema. Puedes ver esas recomendaciones [acá.](https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

Comment: Luego de guardar y salir del editor al escribir "reword", se vuelve a abrir el editor para ingresar el mensaje de commit, tal como explica mgarciaisaia, así que estos pasos no se pueden seguir.

Answer (score 7):

Lo que tenés que hacer es un `rebase` interactivo (`-i`) usando el comando `reword` del mismo.

Primero ejecutá `git rebase -i <hash-del-commit>~1` para pedir hacer `rebase` interactivo de la rama actual a partir del commit anterior (`~1`) al que estás queriendo modificar. Eso disparará tu `$EDITOR` con un listado de todos los commits que existen desde ese hasta el tope de tu rama, indicando `pick`, hash y mensaje de cada uno. Algo como:

```
pick abcdef0 Mensaje del commit más nuevo
pick bcdef01 Mensaje del commit anterior
...
pick fde2152 Mensaje del commit a editar
```

Cambiá `pick` por `r` o `reword` en la línea del commit a editar. Algo así:

```
pick abcdef0 Mensaje del commit más nuevo
pick bcdef01 Mensaje del commit anterior
...
r fde2152 Mensaje del commit a editar
```

Guardá el archivo y salí del editor, y `git` va a volver hasta ese `commit` y disparar el `$EDITOR` nuevamente, pero esta vez con el mensaje del commit ahí presente. Algo como:

```
Mensaje del commit a editar

Este mensaje es el que habías escrito en el primer
git commit, y que ahora querés reemplazar por uno nuevo
```

Editá el mensaje para que quede como querés, grabá el archivo, salí del editor, y `git` aplicará todos los commits que faltaban para que tu rama quede igual, excepto por tener el mensaje actualizado.

No te olvides que **estás modificando la historia de tu repositorio**, por lo que si habías publicado el commit al que estás editando el mensaje o cualquiera de sus sucesores podés generar conflictos al resto de tu equipo.

Answer (score 6):

Esto implica reescribir la historia. Debes tener en cuenta que esta CONTRAINDICADO reescribir la historia de los commits que ya están en un `remote`.

Aclarado esto, puedes reescribir la historia y por lo tanto, cambiar el mensaje de un commit utilizando el comando `git-rebase` con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
git rebase $COMMITID~1
```

Entonces git abre un editor con un contenido similar al siguiente:

```
pick af65427 foo
pick 1d4ba60 bar
pick 9679424 baz
pick 4ac4adc bax
```

En este editor cambias la palabra pick por la palabra reword

```
pick af65427 foo
reword 1d4ba60 bar
pick 9679424 baz
pick 4ac4adc bax
```

Posteriormente, Git abrirá un editor en el que puedes capturar el nuevo mensaje de tu commit.

```
barbarbar

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Author:    asdfasdf <jhon.doe@doe.com>
# Date:      Wed Nov 18 11:45:44 2015 -0600
#
# interactive rebase in progress; onto 1b90076
# Last commands done (2 commands done):
#    pick af65427 actualizacion shells para produccion
#    reword 1d4ba60 acualizacion shell extract_correct_invalid_account
# Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
#    pick 9679424 correccion test, dado que usuario es requerido
#    pick 4ac4adc validacion cuando viene MXP en movimientos de cuenta
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'develop' on '1b90076'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx
#
# Untracked files:
#   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx.log
#   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/foo.txt
```

Una vez que cierres el editor, git reescribira los commits posteriores al reword y actualizará la referencia de tu branch Actual

Saludos